# How to copy only referenced .css to dest with gulp?

Tags: css, gulp

I could use some help with only including referenced css into my production folder. Due to '**/*.css' all css files from my bower_components folder get included. Is there a better way to do that? All necessary css is referenced in my index.html.

my gulp file looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
durandal = require('gulp-durandal');
var dest = '../production';

gulp.task('durandal', function() {
  return durandal({
    almond: true,
    minify: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/app'));
});
gulp.task('statics', function() {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.png', '**/*.css', '**/*.ttf', '**/*.woff', 'index.html', '**/require.js', '!./node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});

gulp.task('build-simple', ['durandal', 'statics']);
```

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE: Solution**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    durandal = require('gulp-durandal'),
    del = require('del'),
    useref = require('gulp-useref'),
    flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
var assets = useref.assets();
var dest = '../dist';

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['../dist/*'], {
        force: true
    });
});
gulp.task('durandal', function() {
    return durandal({
        almond: true,
        minify: true
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/app'));
});
gulp.task('assets', function() {
    return gulp.src('index.html').pipe(assets).pipe(assets.restore()).pipe(useref()).pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['**/*.ttf', '**/*.woff', ]).pipe(flatten()).pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/fonts'));
});
gulp.task('statics', function() {
    return gulp.src(['**/*.png', '**/require.js', '!./node_modules/**']).pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});

gulp.task('production', ['durandal', 'statics', 'assets', 'fonts']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) should be the tool for you, it even concatenates the referred files already:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var assets = useref.assets();


gulp.task('assets', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));   
})
```

You just need to make a few annotations in your html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- build:css css/combined.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- build:css js/combined.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi the combined.css file is created but not referenced in the index.html?

Comment: Okay I had to remove the index.html from the statics task. Now it nearly works. Now it seems it that fonts refs from inside the css files are broken. So I will have to copy those to a matching folder?

Comment: You're welcome! Great that you figured out the rest by yourself :-)